# Can a Teleport be one-way?

Tags: spells, runequest-6

The description in RuneQuest 6 for the Sorcery spell Teleport says that it returns the target to its origin at the end of its duration. That seems not very useful for long-distance teleportation. However, this appears after a section on using Teleport during combat to basically "blink" around. Despite that, nothing in the wording binds the statement about returning to only the "blink" use of Teleport.

This is counter-intuitive enough that while reading it I was certainly *expecting* to read a clarification that the automatic return is limited to that combat use. The earlier mentions of using Marks or Projections to set up Teleports over very long distances does seem to imply that one-way teleports are an *intended* use of the spell.

I can't imagine that one-way long distance teleportation is intended to use the Enchant rules to make the duration permanent, as that makes it a once-in-a-lifetime permanent investment of many Magic Points.

I checked the errata and did some searches to see if this had been discussed online already, but turned up nothing.

**Can Teleport be used one-way, or does the target always return to its origin when the duration elapses?**

Comment: Is there another cheaper instantaneous way to send messages and make deliveries other than using Teleport and Enchant?

Comment: @HeyICanChan As in the answer, the Portal spell does what I was assuming Teleport would. (Teleport is effectively D&D's *blink*, and making it permanent would be similarly limited.) A message-only option would be long-range Telepathy.

Comment: O, yeah. I was just wondering if there was a *reason* to use Teleport over Portal. That is, if making a Teleport item is cheaper and possesses a range like Portal, there's totally a niche for long-range jumps that automatically return *only* the jumper (e.g. warehouse deliveries to a distant warehouse, spy HQ messages to a dead drop). (BTW, I am totally system unaware (my last *Runequest* was *2*), but I *am* a fan of teleportation.)

Comment: @Hey Ohh, I see what you mean. Hm. Casting costs are flexible and I haven't worked them out, so—maybe? :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Teleport spell as written (on p. 254-255) is pretty explicit - at the end of the duration, dead or alive, the subject returns to their origin point. It's also almost explicit that it's a combat travel spell.

Note that Summon works almost exactly the same, except that it brings a person or thing to the caster, where it remains for the duration, then goes back where it began.

The spell for one-way travel is Portal, not Teleport. (p. 248.)